# Arrays or key-value pairs in workflow

Tags: github, github-actions

In GitHub Actions, is there a way to pass an array or a key-value pair as a parameter? I have not seen these inputs used.

Answer (score 0):

No, [only numbers, strings, and booleans are supported](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onworkflow_callinputsinput_idtype) for input types. However, you can use JSON-formatted strings, which can be parsed by the code running in the Action.

For example, you might pass an array like follows:

```yaml
    uses: octo-org/example-repo/.github/workflows/called-workflow.yml@main
    with:
      param_name: '["foo", "bar"]'
```

Then the action can parse the string input into the respective data structure.

There are also builtin functions like [`fromJSON` and `toJSON`](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#tojson) to help ease that process.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like multi-choice drop-down is not available. If it is available, that's another option. Multi-choice is permitted through option?

Comment: @testbgtestbg you can configure [choices](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#example-of-onworkflow_dispatchinputs) but the type of the choice can still only be a number, string, or boolean.